# How to join column to table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
#Collect the compound values for each news source
score_table = df.pivot_table(index='User',  values="Compound", aggfunc = np.mean)
score_table 



from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
a = dict(Counter(HT_positive))
t = list(a.items()) 
compound = score_table["Compound"]
df = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=["Hashtags", "Number of Occurence"])
df4 = df.append(compound)
df.to_csv('hashtags.csv', index=False)
df4_saved_file = pd.read_csv('hashtags.csv')
df4_saved_file
```

I'm getting a KeyError: "Compound". I understand how to add the "Compound" column in between "Hashtags" and "Number of Occurence"

Comment: Check if there are any spaces in the column names.

Comment: What is `score_table` ? Will you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68355457/edit) to include a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a small bit of code that we can easily copy and run).

Comment: @HenryEcker I added the score_table to the top of the code, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could check if "Compound" or "User" should be the key that you use to query the value from the dictionary.

Comment: Where would I add this key, or how so?

Comment: It is not quite about adding the key, but about using the correct key. The error indicates that in `score_table` there is no column named as "Compound".